# Create a template header-only project library file

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

My C++ project is completely based on templates and so my code is split in different header files (header-only project).
But for the users of the library I want to provide one header file ("library file"), they have to include to use the library.
One possibility would be to copy all the code in one file by hand, but if the project is bigger I want to create the file automatically with `make`. So my idea was to set up the library file, where I include all the source files and process this with `g++ -E` (just preprocess). But the preprocessor anyhow writes the contents included files, which are included in multiple files (i.e. `<string>`), also multiple times into the output files. This causes 'multiple definition' errors when I use the library.

So is there a possibility to prevent the multiple copying or is there another method I could use to achieve my goal to get one library file?

If you need some example code to answer the question, just leave a comment.

Example:

header.h:

```
#ifndef CSV_H_
#define CSV_H_

#include <deque>
#include <istream>
#include <string>

using std::deque;
using std::istream;
using std::string;

namespace csv {

template<typename T>
class csv_parser {
private:
    deque<T> line;
public:
    template<typename S>
    friend csv_parser<S>& operator>> (istream& input, csv_parser<S>& parser); //file input stream operator
    deque<T>& operator>> (deque<T>& target); //data output operator
    deque<T> get_line(); //get parsed line
    void set_line(string input);  //set line and parse
};
#endif
```

definition.h:

```
#include <deque>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "../headers/csv.h"

using std::deque;
using std::istream;
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;
using std::getline;
using std::copy;

namespace csv {

template<typename T>
csv_parser<T>& operator>> (istream& input, csv_parser<T>& parser) {
    parser.line.clear(); //clear the data
    T buffer;
    string line;
    stringstream converter;

    getline(input, line); //get one line from csv file

    while (line.size() > 0) { //get field from csv line and delete this segment until
                              //input line is empty
        if (line.find_first_of(",") != -1) { //(not the last segment [one ',' left])
            converter << line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")); //add segment to converter
            converter >> buffer; //convert segment to T type
            converter.clear(); //clear flags of converter (normally EOF flag is set
                                //after converting), so writing in converter is enabled again
            parser.line.push_back(buffer); //write segment into data
            line.erase(0, line.find_first_of(",")+1); //delete segment from input line
        }
        else { //(last segment in line)
            converter << line.substr(0, line.length()); //get rest of the line
            converter >> buffer; //convert segment to T type
            converter.clear(); //clear flags of converter (normally EOF flag is set
                               //after converting), so writing in converter is enabled again
            parser.line.push_back(buffer);//write segment into data
            line.erase(0, line.length()); //delete rest of input string
        }
    }
    return parser;
}

template<typename T>
void csv_parser<T>::set_line(string input) {
    line.clear();
    T buffer;
    stringstream converter;

    while (input.size() > 0) { //get field from input and delete this segment until
                              //input is empty
        if (input.find_first_of(",") != -1) { //(not the last segment [one ',' left])
            converter << input.substr(0, input.find_first_of(",")); //add segment to converter
            converter >> buffer; //convert segment to T type
            converter.clear(); //clear flags of converter (normally EOF flag is set
                                //after converting), so writing in converter is enabled again
            line.push_back(buffer); //write segment into data
            input.erase(0, input.find_first_of(",")+1); //delete segment from input
        }
        else { //(last segment in line)
            converter << input.substr(0, input.length()); //get rest of the input
            converter >> buffer; //convert segment to T type
            converter.clear(); //clear flags of converter (normally EOF flag is set
                               //after converting), so writing in converter is enabled again
            line.push_back(buffer);//write segment into data
            input.erase(0, input.length()); //delete rest of input
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
deque<T>& csv_parser<T>::operator>>(deque<T>& target) {//write parsed data into target
    target.clear();
    target.assign(line.begin(), line.end()); //copy data into target
    line.clear(); //delete data
    return target;
}

template<typename T>
deque<T> csv_parser<T>::get_line(){ //return data
    deque<T> buffer = line; //copy data into buffer
    line.clear(); //delete data
    return buffer; //return buffer
}

}
```

(uncompiled) library.h:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "definition.h"
```

Compiler directive:

```
g++ -E library.h -o library_out.h
```

So if I use library_out.h in an application, symbols, that are part of i.e. the deque header, are defined multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copy the contents of all the header files into one giant header file, consider using `#include` statements.

mylibrary.h:

```
#include "myfile1.h"
#include "myfile2.h"
#include "myfile3.h"
```

Comment: I exactly do this, wait a second, I post some example code.

Answer (score 1):

If your library is header only, you have to mark all non-template functions (including specializations) as `inline`. Otherwise, including a header in multiple TU leads to multiple definitions linking error.

Example:

```
// header.h
inline void f(){}

// p1.cpp
#include "header.h"

// p2.cpp
#include "header.h"
```

Compiling now `p1.cpp` and `p2.cpp` is fine, no more symbol duplication errors.

Comment: Im not sure if we mean the same, not my own functions get included mulitple, but external librarys like string or deque.

Comment: Including `std` files should not create any problems. One option is to include all your library files into a single header file, then include that header file into your future project.

Comment: so here is my example